# Multiple constraints in generic class gave casting error in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I want to explain my title of this question.

I have the base class

```
 public class BaseClass { /* stuff */ }
```

And other two classes which inherits `BaseClass`

```
  public class Test1: BaseClass {  ... }

  public class Test2: BaseClass { ... }
```

Ok then let assume with generic class (in my project it is very complex)

```
  public GenericClass<T> : IBase<T> where T: BaseClass, Test1, Test2
```

Sometimes I need to use only `BaseClass` otherwise `Test1` or `Test2`.

I have a function:

```
  public int Create ( T obj){
    if( obj is Test1) { return aManager.Create((Test1)obj); } // the cast is OK
    else if(obj is Test2) { return bManager.Create((Test2)obj);}  // error cast
  }
```

I have also `aManager.Create (Test1 obj)` and `bManager.Create(Test2 obj)`

Why in the `else` row I have error in cast?

Where is my mistake?

**PS**: If I change the order between `Test1` and `Test2` then in first `if` will occur casting error and in `else` will be ok.

Comment: `where T: BaseClass, Test1, Test2` combines classes with `AND`, not `OR`, so your class has to satisfy all these constraints.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176908/c-sharp-multiple-generic-constraints

Comment: No matter, is a simple class which add an object

Comment: @SnakeEyes: that matters, the way you use if else in order to do just casting is really messy, why you process inside `Create` method

Comment: I think the problem is here `public int Create ( T obj){`. You need to declare it `public int Create (object obj){`

Comment: `if( obj is Test1)` and `else if(obj is Test2)` don't make sense at all, bacause `where T: BaseClass, Test1, Test2` (i.e. any `T` must be of type `Test1` and `Test2`, which is impossible since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Would you suggest to use something like: `GenericClass<T1, T2>  where T1: BaseClass, Test1 where T2: BaseClass, Test2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how generic type constraints work. Let me start by first answering your question.

You actually only need the signature like this.

```
public GenericClass<T> : IBase<T> where T: BaseClass
```

> which means, the type T is any type that derives from type BaseClass
>   or the BaseClass itself.

It will very well accept any instances of type BaseClass, Test1 and Test2.

Further, I'd like to suggest an improvement in your code..

```
public int Create ( T obj){
    if( obj is Test1) { return aManager.Create(obj as Test1); } // the cast is OK
    else if(obj is Test2) { return bManager.Create(obj as Test2);}  // error cast
  }
```

However, I believe that the design of your code has some loop holes. If you could explain your context in more detail, you might get better design solutions for your problem. Since I believe this is more to do with the design than the generics as it seems you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as both the `Test1` and the `Test2` are class, this line is not true.

```
public GenericClass<T> : IBase<T> where T: BaseClass, Test1, Test2
```

Because just one base class is allowed in generic type constrains and it must come as the first constraint, however you can have multiple interface types as constraint. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

To see what I mean change the `Create` method like this and you will see the error:

```
public int Create ( T obj)
{
//if( obj is Test1) { return aManager.Create((Test1)obj); } // the cast is OK
//else if(obj is Test2) { return bManager.Create((Test2)obj);}  // error cast
    return 1;
}
```